Installing Laravel Breeze on a Docker container ("npm not found")
I'm new to Docker, so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.
I am creating a new Laravel application using Docker following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@murilolivorato/setting-up-a-laravel-development-environment-with-docker-and-docker-compose-a-step-by-step-5e37670ae640
I can get the Laravel application running on Docker, no problem. However, I run into problems when I attempt to install Laravel Breeze.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation
First I run:
docker-compose run --rm composer require laravel/breeze --dev

Success! Then I run:
docker-compose run --rm artisan breeze:install

I get the following error:
sh: npm: not found

Also, if I run this command:
docker-compose run --rm npm install && npm run dev

I get this error:
no such service: npm

I've researched how to install npm on the container, but I cannot seem to understand how the Dockerfiles work and on which container I need to install it. My tutorial has the code broken out into several Dockerfiles. Here is my code:
docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.9"

networks:
  laravel_environment:

services:
  server:
    # image: 'nginx:stable-alpine'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      # - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
      - redis
      - mysql
      - mailhog
    container_name: laravel_environment_server
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
    # extra_hosts:
    #  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    container_name: php_environment
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.1
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    container_name: mysql_environment
    env_file:
      - mysql/.env
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
    volumes:
      - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: phpmyadmin_environment
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - '8891:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mysql
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=secret
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis_environment
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes --replica-read-only no

  composer:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: ["php", "/var/www/html/artisan"]
      #depends_on:
    #- mysql
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
  scheduler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    container_name: scheduler_environment
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: [ "php", "artisan", "schedule:work" ]
    networks:
      - laravel_environment
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    container_name: mailhog_environment
    ports:
      - 1025:1025
      - 8025:8025
    networks:
      - laravel_environment

composer.dockerfile:
FROM composer:latest

RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

USER laravel

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENTRYPOINT [ "composer", "--ignore-platform-reqs" ]

nginx.dockerfile:
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

WORKDIR /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY nginx/default.conf .

RUN mv default.conf default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY src .

php.dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY src .
# Instalando extensões necessárias do PHP
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-essentials \
    icu-dev icu-libs zlib-dev g++ make automake autoconf libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    apk del build-essentials && rm -rf /usr/src/php*

RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        && pecl install redis \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so

RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

RUN chown -R laravel /var/www/html

USER laravel

Thank you for any help!

You should install node, for that you can modify php.dockerfile:
add nodejs npm like below and restart your docker container.

RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu nodejs npm

